# NextJs go to new page without refreshing the page and changing the states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a `NextJS` app and I am trying to add dynamic routes to use them as endpoints on my server.

I have a `register.tsx` file which is loaded when I go to `localhost:3000/register`

Inside one of the components I want to update the link to `/register/user/` however, when I use:

```
useEffect(() => {
        router.push('/user', undefined, { shallow: true })
    }, [])
```

Inside my component in goes to a completely new page and loses all the states. How can I achieve this. I have this in my `server.ts` file:

```
app.post("/register/user", async (req, res) => {
    
})
```

**EDIT**

I was able to fix the issue by changing the file structure of the application to

```
pages
--register
----[[..slug]].tsx
```

However, right now:

```
app.post("/register/user", async (req, res) => {

})
```

returns an html object wheres I have set it to return a JSON object

Answer (score 2):

You need to move your `state` up, **above** all pages in the component hierarchy, so when the pages change, the state stays the same.
In your `_app.js` file you could have a `provider` that wraps the `page component` that way every page will have access to the data.
For example like this:

```js
        <AuthProvider
          options={{
            clientMaxAge: 0 //60 * 60
          }}
          session={pageProps.session}
        >
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </AuthProvider>
```

Now all pages will have access to the data provided by the `AuthProvider`